# Do you know any video tutorials on UML diagrams?

Tags: oop, uml

Can you please recommend video tutorials on how to read and draw most common UML diagrams?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkC7HKtiZC0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Tube is your friend.

Here is a video showing UML Diagrams: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7JXUS4NK2w&feature=related

Look at the right hand side, under suggestions for others.
Alternatively search You Tube.